# Unable to send mails

Tags: php, jquery

I have an HTML form, and linked with jQuery and PHP. The jQuery check whether the fields or empty or not, if they are not empty, it should send the data to the PHP file. But its not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();

    $("#returnmessage").empty(); // To empty previous error/success message.
    // Checking for blank fields.
    if (name == '') {
      alert(" Please Fill your name");
    } else if (message == '') {
      alert("Please Fill message");
    } else {
      $.post("xxx.php", { // To php file.
        name: name,
        message: message
      }, function(data) {
        $("#returnmessage").append(data);
        if (data == "We will contact you soon.") {
          $("#form")[0].reset(); // To reset form fields on success.
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
  <h4>FEED-BACK FORM</h4>
  <p id="returnmessage"></p>
  <label>Name:  </label>
  <input type="text" id="name" /><br>
  <label>Message:  </label>
  <input type="text" id="message" /><br>
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

THE PHP CODE IS:

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
       {
    //Need to submit the form.
    exit;
       }
$name = $_POST['name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$email_body ="Dear sir,\n".
"Name: $name\n". 
"Message:    $message\n";

//Email sending to
$email_from = 'xxx@xxx.xxx';
$email_subject = "my-form";
$to = "xxx@xxxx";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
```

Comment: Anything in the console? You should indent your code blocks.

Comment: I think there might be wrong in code.

Comment: @user3410277 Your code seems alright... What's happening? Can you show your `POST` AJAX call? Using the Network tab?

Comment: If there is empty, the JS is giving pop-up message but when there is data, it it is not posting to php file.

Comment: @user3410277 How do you know if it is not posting to the PHP? What's the URL you are using? Please show us a screenshot of your Console, Network tab.

Comment: <?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
       {
 //Need to submit the form.
 exit;
       }
$name = $_POST['name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$email_body ="Dear sir,\n".
"Name: $name\n". 
"Message:    $message\n";

//Email sending to
$email_from = 'xxx@xxx.xxx';
$email_subject = "my-form";
$to = "xxx@xxxx";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

?>

Comment: Add that to the question using the `edit` link below the tags.

Comment: @user3410277 Please [edit] your posts.

Comment: At least add an error handler to the ajax. You have to narrow this down as to where it's not working before even fixing the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using this check:

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit']))
```

And this would mostly never execute because of how you `POST` the data to the server and also, how each browser will take it. Especially Chrome, will not `POST` the `submit`. It mostly depends on the data that the AJAX is sending, so you need to see what's it sending:

[image]

Instead of your code, use:

```
if (count($_POST) == 0)
  exit;
```

And also, make sure you have set up your `mail()` function to work with SMTP or which ever, in your `php.ini`. Only **you** could check your console, what the server response. So, give more details to your client like:

```
if (mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers))
  die("Success");
else
  die("Failed");
```

The above part will help to diagnose where the script went wrong. At the same time, before exiting in the first part, respond with a message. Instead of your code, use:

```
if (count($_POST) == 0)
  die("Need to POST");
```

Also on the client side, make sure you use the latest or pretty decent version of jQuery (version > 1.9.1).

---

Looks like the OP needs more detailed explanation to find the bug. Could be helpful for others:

1. Open your URL in **Chrome**. Please tell us what **URL** are you using in your address bar.
2. Once the page is loaded, **press <kbd>F12</kbd> button**. This brings up the Console.
3. If that didn't work, right click and select **Inspect**, then click on **Console**. Make sure to clear console first by clicking on the Cross button.
4. **Reload** the page. See if there are any Errors in Console.
5. Tell us what do you see in the Console and after giving information, click on the Network tab, click submit, see if you have any activity.

Waiting for further responses.

---

**Update:**

You are checking in the `success` method:

```
if (data == "We will contact you soon.")
```

But where are you sending it in the PHP file? You need this at the end of the PHP file.

```
echo "We will contact you soon.";
```

Comment: Actually not even browser dependent ... only dependent on the ajax data

Comment: @charlietfl Sometimes buddy. jQuery dependent.

Comment: @user3410277 Please, please, explain. So when you are saying it's not working, tell us clearly, where it went wrong. Did the AJAX call go? Did it fail in the `POST` or did it fail in the `mail()`?

Comment: @user3410277 Kindly check the updated answer for a detailed expectation from us.

Comment: @user3410277 Refresh the page, see the answer and please answer my questions. `:)`

Comment: @Praveen, Thank you it is working. The data is posted in email.  But when the its success, the pop-up window is not showing any message.

Comment: @user3410277 You are checking: `(data == "We will contact you soon.")`, but where are you sending it in the PHP file? You need `echo "We will contact you soon."`.

Comment: Been thinking for long time that we need a good canonical question on the site for "My ajx doesn't work". So many people have no idea to start in network and would save lots of time

Comment: @charlietfl Lemme create one! `:)`

Comment: I actually started some markdown for answer one day. Better to get  lot of the answer built first before posting question. Include dev tools screenshot etc and how to inspect in dev tools....add error handlers etc

Comment: @Mr. Praveen,  when it is success, the pop-up message to be appeared "We will contact you soon"

Comment: @user3410277 Please refresh my answer and see the update. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr. Praveen, the message to be appeared in HTML form from Jquery  not in php

Answer (score 0):

I have try your code but not get error. Run code.
Which version using your jQuery lib?

Are you please try with

> jQuery lib 2.2
>   https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js

As this?

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#submit").click(function() {
    var data_name = jQuery("#name").val();
    var data_message = jQuery("#message").val();
    jQuery("#returnmessage").empty(); // To empty previous error/success message.
    // Checking for blank fields.
      if (data_name == '' ) {
        alert(" Please Fill your name");
      } else if(data_message == '' ) {
        alert("Please Fill message");
      } else { 
        jQuery.post("xxx.php", { // To php file.
            name: data_name, message: data_message
        }, function(data) {
            jQuery("#returnmessage").append(data); 
          if (data == "We will contact you soon.") {
            jQuery("#form")[0].reset(); // To reset form fields on success.
          }
        });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: @Mr. Berk, I am using ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js but it is not wroking

Comment: @user3410277 Code works at me with 1.11.0. Not continuous warning. 
Browse please sample; https://jsfiddle.net/m6eLjajs/